# How to remove escape \' character from the mail body, mail sent PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

why I am getting the backslash () before the singlequote (') in my email body? email sent through PHPMailer.

Scenario:
In email : "I don\'t know who is Kiku!"
[email screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hQGa.png)
In database : "I don't know who is Kiku!"
[database screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZJf5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because someone messed up the code for sending the mail, most likely by redundantly escaping the string to send, thinking it will increase security. That's really all I can give you.